# Adding Firebase Auth UI to an App with existing users with mysql database

Tags: laravel, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, google-authentication

Recently I am working on a laravel app that has quite a few users already when I think about it I have two possible solutions to integrate firebase auth to the app

1. create a separate auth guard in laravel that verifies firebase token and saves a user in laravel database.

   1.1 if a user is already existing save UUID to the user table and login that user in laravel.

   1.2 if it's a new user create a user along with UUID
   (Redundancy two copy of users are saved, one in the local database, one at firebase auth)
2. completely migrate the laravel default user system to firebase auth.

Is there any pitfall that I should be aware of before proceeding?